# Different results when when using ddply and summarize. Due to different R and plyr versions?

Tags: r, plyr

I'm looking to summarize data similar to the ToothGrowth data in the datasets package.

The output I want looks like this:

```
  supp   len  half   one   two
1   OJ 619.9 132.3 227.0 260.6
2   VC 508.9  79.8 167.7 261.4
```

That is the sum of lengths split by dose and supplement type. My colleague gets this output using R version 2.15.1 and plyr_1.7.1 using the following code.

```
library(datasets)           

x <- ToothGrowth

test <- ddply(x,c("supp"),summarize,
                     len = sum(len,na.rm=TRUE),
                     half = sum(len[dose==0.5],na.rm=TRUE),
                     one = sum(len[dose==1],na.rm=TRUE),
                     two = sum(len[dose==2],na.rm=TRUE))
```

There are no NAs in the ToothGrowth data but there are in the real dataset.

I get the following output R version 3.0.0 and and plyr_1.8. I can provide full sessionInfo() for both if that would be useful.

```
    supp    len half    one two
1   OJ    619.9 619.9   0   0
2   VC    508.9 508.9   0   0
```

This doesn't seem to bring up an error. In my data I only have three 'doses' but lots of 'supplement types'. Where there are no values in the half category it puts the whole sum into one, or two.

Is there a way in which I can do this that will produce a consistent output across versions types?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `ddply` was updated to "mutate by default" so to speak. So in the last three variables, when you refer to `len`, you are actually referring to the `len` variable you just created, which is only a single value. Call it something else.

Comment: @joran I'd say don't hesitate to put this as the anwser.

Comment: @joran, any comments on why this change (or a link perhaps if it's not much trouble for you)?

Comment: @Arun I put a link to the github issue+pull request in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`summarise` was updated to "mutate by default" so to speak. So in the last three variables, when you refer to `len`, you are actually referring to the `len` variable you just created, which is only a single value. Call it something else:

```
test <- ddply(x,c("supp"),summarize,
+                      len1 = sum(len,na.rm=TRUE),
+                      half = sum(len[dose==0.5],na.rm=TRUE),
+                      one = sum(len[dose==1],na.rm=TRUE),
+                      two = sum(len[dose==2],na.rm=TRUE))
> test
  supp  len1  half   one   two
1   OJ 619.9 132.3 227.0 260.6
2   VC 508.9  79.8 167.7 261.4
```

(I originally mistakenly called this a change in `ddply`.) As for why, I suppose because it seemed like it would be convenient, and people requested the change. [Here](https://github.com/hadley/plyr/issues/44) is a link to the issue raised and the subsequent patch.